# SQL Calculated Column based on OVER PARTITION BY Clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a view with a ROW NUMBER based on a PARTITION BY across some columns.
The ROW NUMBER starts at 0 and increments for each record based on ssis inputs from various files,
for each file with a unique filename and date combination, there will be row numbers from 0 - n.

Now i need to do create a new column that does a calculation on a value, using the row number.

```
RowNumber Value Filename FileDate  
0           500   datax   20200301  
1           200   datax   20200301  
2           100   datax   20200301  
0           600   datax   20200302  
1           200   datax   20200302  
2           200   datax   20200302  
3           100   datax   20200302  
4           200   datax   20200302  
0           700   datay   20200303  
1           500   datay   20200303
```

I want a new column that divides the values from each RowNumber n by the value in RowNumber 0, for its unique partition

```
NEWVALUE = (Value @ RowNumber N / Value at RowNumber 0)

RowNumber Value  NEWVALUE          Filename FileDate  
0           500   NULL             datax   20200301  
1           200   0.400            datax   20200301  
2           100   0.200            datax   20200301  
0           600   NULL             datax   20200302  
1           200   0.333            datax   20200302  
2           200   0.333            datax   20200302  
3           100   0.167            datax   20200302  
4           300   0.500            datax   20200302  
0           700   NULL             datay   20200303  
1           500   0.714            datay   20200303
```

Anyone know how to do this

Comment: "across some columns" - Oh goody, we get to guess - is it across `FileDate`? And I could guess the `ORDER BY` is on `Value` descending. It's not clear whether `Filename` is relevant, but this would all be a *lot* easier if you just showed us the *actual* `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: Have a look at `FIRST_VALUE`.

Comment: As @Larnu, Suggested you just need a window function as FIrST_VALUE. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @404, OP doesn't needs previous but first value in the partition.

Comment: FIRST_VALUE did the trick, thank you @Gordon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select ( value * 1.0 /
         max(case when rownumber = 0 then value end) over (partition by filename, filedate)
         value
       ) as ratio
```

I am guessing that the partitioning groups are based on `filename` and `filegroup`.

Or use `first_value()`:

```
select ( value * 1.0 /
         first_value(value) over (partition by filename, filedate order by rownumber)
         value
       ) as ratio
```

To put either of these into the view, you'll need a subquery.

If the ordering is based on the maximum value, then you can use similar logic (and dispense with the subquery):

```
select ( value * 1.0 /
         max(value) over (partition by filename, filedate)  * 1.0
         value
       ) as ratio
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have suggested ROWNUM = 0 is equivalent of FIRST_VALUE

The tricky bit is adding a null for NEWVALUE instead of 1, you will have to resort to a subquery.

```
SELECT 
RowNumber,Value,CASE WHEN RowNumber=0 THEN NULL else NEWVALUE end as NEWVALUE, FileName,FileDate
FROM (
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PArtition BY FileDate ORDER BY Value DESC) -1 as RowNumber,
  Value,
  Value * 1.0 / FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER (PArtition BY FileDate ORDER BY Value DESC) as NEWVALUE
  ,FileName
  ,FileDate
  from Data
  ) t
```

Here's the sqlfiddle if you would like to play around with it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2bdca4/1